# How to limit external access to mail server?

Tags: firewall, email-server, access-control-list, mdaemon

I use Mdaemon mail server.

It can be accessed from internal network and from internet (using mail client and web interface).

The problem is I need to limit which users can access their mails from the internet.

I thought about doing IP-based filtering via firewall, but I cannot control which IP users use to access the server.

Is there any mail server out there which can do what I want? Any other ways I can implement this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

In the Account Editor in MDaemon you can configure users to access via POP, IMAP and the WorldClient only from LAN IP's.

The settings are under Mail Services and Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a client called Remote Administration that you can use to restrict access. If they're on Activesync, just disable it on their account.

http://www.altn.com/Products/MDaemon-Email-Server-Windows/MDaemon-Remote-Administration/